# How can I modify a MySQL query to work in Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: mysql, sql, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have to write a SQL query in Report Builder 3.0 that'll run on MySQL DB. I am also passing 3 parameters to this query and one of these parameters will be a column name. The query structure like this:

```
SELECT
  column1
  ,column21
  ,column15
  ,column6
  ,column9
  ,column2
  ,column19
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  column1 LIKE @var_1 --@var_1 is a string
  AND column21 LIKE @var_2 --@var_1 is a string
  AND (@column is null OR @column = '' OR @column = 'N/A' OR @column = 'Unknown');--value in @column is an existing column name from table table_name
```

I have a SQL that does what I want and works from MySQL workbench:

```
SET @var_1 = 'string1';
SET @var_2 = 'string2';
SET @columnName = 'string3';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT
  column1
  ,column21
  ,column15
  ,column6
  ,column9
  ,column2
  ,column19
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  column1 LIKE @var_1
  AND column21 LIKE @var_2
  AND (', @columnName ,' is null OR ', @columnName ,' = \'\' OR ', @columnName ,' = \'N/A\' OR ', @columnName ,' = \'Unknown\')');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**But my question is:** How can I write this in Query Designer of Report Builder 3.0?
I have tried something like following SQL in Report Builder and it's variations on same lines as the working query:

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT
  column1
  ,column21
  ,column15
  ,column6
  ,column9
  ,column2
  ,column19
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  column1 LIKE ''%' + @var_1 + '%''
  AND column21 LIKE ''%' + @var_2 + '%''
  AND (', @column ,' is null OR ', @column ,' = \'\' OR ', @column ,' = \'N/A\' OR ', @column ,' = \'Unknown\')');

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

But I keep getting error:

> An error occurred while executing the query.
>
> ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.1.73]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
>
> EXECUTE stmt;
>
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt' at line 3 (Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder)

How can I write this SQL with correct syntax so it works in Report Builder?

Comment: You have to write it so that it's correct SQL syntax, regardless of what tool you use to execute it. First clue: You never close the () on the CONCAT function.

Comment: Thank you pointing that out. I have added a closing parenthesis after Unknown. Also I have added the working SQL that fetches data as expected when run from  MySQL workbench. But problem running same query from Query Designer of Report Builder is that it doesn't prompt for `@var_1` and `@var_2` so I had to update the query so that it does prompts for all three variables.  After all this the query still gives same error when tried from Report Builder.

Comment: __Edit your answer__ with the updated code. Also, you might trying to see what @SQL contains before the prepare. Try executing that by itself to see if you get a more specific error message.

Comment: 3rd SQL in my question is what I am trying through Report Builder. It's under line "So, I have tried something like following SQL and it's variations on same lines as the working query:" Per your suggestion tried to execute @SQL without using prepare, and got same error but for "EXECUTE @SQL". The error is `ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.1.73]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXECUTE @SQL' at line 3 (Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder)` Tried `SELECT @SQL` but same error.

Comment: I wasn't saying to execute the @SQL, but to display it so you can see where the syntax error is in the statement that you prepare and execute. Hard to debug a SQL statement when you can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to prepare and execute the query in the Query Designer of Report Builder. Depending on the database type you specified in the datasource, you just have to write the query and Report builder will handle the execution.

So just enter this in the query designer :

```
SELECT
  column1
  ,column21
  ,column15
  ,column6
  ,column9
  ,column2
  ,column19
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  column1 LIKE ''%' + @var_1 + '%''
  AND column21 LIKE ''%' + @var_2 + '%''
  AND (', @column ,' is null OR ', @column ,' = \'\' OR ', @column ,' = \'N/A\' OR ', @column ,' = \'Unknown\')'
```

Alternatively, have you tried building the query by clicking on the "Query Designer" button at the bottom of the query text box? This way, you can specify which table to get your data from without typing an SQL query and risking a naming or syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried running only the query after removing CONCAT, PREPARE and EXECUTE but then it gave syntax errors. The reason was escape characters and other syntax which was there for CONCAT. So I removed all the extra syntax and ran the simple query but it doesn't pull any record. If I run the same query directly on MySQL DB by replacing 3 variables with their values it does fetch records. Difference in behavior is because the third variable @column is a column name. When Report Builder replaces it, it places quotes around it considering it a string. It's column name.

Comment: That was the reason I was trying to use dynamic query as one of the parameters was actually a column name. I think somehow the Report Builder is not working well with `PREPARE...EXECUTE....DEALLOCATE` or just `EXECUTE`. I am guessing this because no matter how I change the query in Report Builder it always gives error at first line after the `SET @SQL =CONCAT('....@column ,' = \'Unknown\')');`

Comment: Are you trying to edit the sql query of a dataset? If so, you can change the values of the query parameters in the "parameters" tab on the left. I don't think you can set the parameters in the query per se.